# when adding array of object to realm in swift only the last object added

Tags: swift, database, realm

I try to add array of object in Realm but only the last object added i don't know why if any one can help me

```
func insertAllCategories(categories:[Category]){
    print(categories.count)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        for cat in categories{
            realm.add(cat)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the array and the call:

```
var categories=[Category]()

var cat1=Category()
cat1.id=1 
cat1.catName="cat1" 
cat1.catId=9 
cat1.catType=2 
categories.append(cat1) 

var cat2=Category() 
cat2.id=2
cat2.catName="cat2"
cat2.catId=19
cat2.catType=2
categories.append(cat2) 

insertAllCategories(categories: categories)
```

Comment: If the id is the same they will become 1 object, so make sure they have different values for id.

Comment: The id is different I am sure

Comment: Why would you add all objects one by one when you can add an array of objects as well? Just write `try! realm.write {
        realm.add(categories)
    }`